# Meaning of the dollar sign($)

Tags: c#

I was reading up on socket programming and i saw a sample code. 
The thing i dont understand is the meaning of the dollar sign($).

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(massConvoMsg + "$");
```

Does it mean that it is a string? or?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a string. It will simply be appended to the end of `massConvoMsg` and the combined thing treated is single string.

Answer (score 10):

Someone is adding the literal dollar sign character to the end of the massConvoMsg string, and encoding the result to bytes.

It has no special meaning to c#

Answer (score 5):

it is in quotes. So It's string
All that you use in quotes are strings. (not only in C#, in a lot of languages)

Comment: The "all" is misleading, as both c# string literal forms (and character literals) have escape chars

Answer (score 0):

in a simple concept:

You are trying to join the `massConvoMsg`'s variable into a string type by just concatenating it with a string symbol of "`$`".

You can put anything such as `massConvoMsg + "a"` or `massConvoMsg + "dsadadsa"` or whatever string you want.

At the end you might want to get the output by ignoring the joined string, then you need to implement some kind of substring method. Example:

```
substring(massConvoMsg, 0, "$"); // This will remove the $ sign.
```

The question, why you choose dollar sign ($)? Because it's more readable, simple and unique. Right?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange Network. This is not a bullet-in board or chatroom, but a professional questions and answer site, so please use proper spelling, grammar, and punctuation. I have corrected your answer, but please do it yourself in the future.

Comment: thanks for formatting my answer. im a senior member and that was my quick post :D